# Excel 2007 drop-down list that effects the cell's color but not the content

Tags: excel, list, drop-down-menu, colors, background

I have searched for this solution and I have found many drop-down lists that can change the color and the data of the cell or change the color depending on what data is entered.

What I would like to do is have a cell with a number inside (#'s 1-10) and also have a drop-down list (pass, fail, marginal) and depending on which item from the drop-down list is selected it would change the cell's background color to red, green, or yellow, from it's default of white.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: From what I understand, you want to change the background color of the #s cell depending on the value of the drop down list. Am I right?

Comment: That is correct, Konstant. But I would like the drop-down to have no effect on the data that is in the cell.

Comment: If the answer posted solves your problem, then please "accept" it and upvote it. Thanks

Comment: Michael, please accept an answer, otherwise it remains in the "unanswered" list and people waste time on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional formatting to achieve the same. For the cells with numbers add conditional formatting

1. Home -> Conditional formatting -> New Rule
2. Select `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`. Now you set a formula here. You can refer to drop-down list value here to set format. (eg: if column A has numbers and column B has the drop-down, you can set the formula as `=$B1="Marginal"` and set the formatting.

Hope this helps.

Screenshots for reference:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, Konstant.  What if I want the drop-down list and the cell with the data to be the same cell.  Example: I have a cell with data and also a dropdown list.  Depending on what Item in the list is selected, the cell's color changes but the data remains the same.  In other words, I don't want the selection of the drop down menu to be visible in the cell, I just want it to change the cell's color and leave the contents of the cell untouched.

Comment: I don't think that is directly possible but it can be definitely achieved via a macro. Since a cell can contain only one value at a time, you cannot have a selection based on drop down in the same cell and not change the value. The drop down will change the cell value. When you write a macro, you would store the previous value -> get the changed value from "drop-down" (that would be Pass, Fail, Marginal) -> set the background color -> set the value back to the original value

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the best solution for this situation:

I had two cells side by side.  One with the data and one with the drop-down box.  The two cells bordered together so that they appear as one cell (even though they aren't).  I then put two separate conditional formats on the two cells.  The conditional format of the data cell changed the background color of the cell based on the value of the drop-down box cell. The conditional format of the drop-down box cell changed the background and text color to the same color as the other cell (to blend in) depending on its own value.

When the two cells were bordered and spaced correctly they appear as being one cell with one value.  Quite a bit of work with the formatting and all but I think this may be the best option for this situation.

Thanks again, Konstant for your help. :)

Comment: clever solution i must say :) Please upvote my answer if it helped. thanks